# Audiokit crashes when enabling sandbox in OS X

Tags: swift, macos, microphone, appstore-sandbox, audiokit

My app using Audiokit is running perfectly without sandbox. But as soon as I enable sandbox in Xcode the app crashes when trying to initialize the mic access.
(The app is on the App Store for iOS, but now I am trying to submit to the Mac Store as a OS X app but I need to enable sandbox)

Has anyone been able to submit a Mac app to the Mac App Store with Audiokit in it?

> ERROR: >avae> AVAudioEngine.mm:275: AttachNode: required condition
>   is false: `node != nil`

Comment: Could you post your entitlements file?

Comment: please post code where and how you init microphone node. To check for errors coming from sandbox you'll have to check console log outside of Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

To enable microphone access in App Store sandbox you'll need to add following entitlement:

```
com.apple.security.device.audio-input
```

See [reference of Sandbox: Enabling Hardware Access](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW11)

Comment: didn't work for me. I still get the same error. I've also added com.apple.security.microphone, still get the same crash

Answer (score 0):

This entitlements file did work for me. But it doesn't cover all the cases.
Please check Apple documentation for more details https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2312/_index.html

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
  <true/>
  <key>com.apple.security.device.audio-input</key>
  <true/>
  <key>com.apple.security.device.audio-video-bridging</key>
  <true/>
  <key>com.apple.security.files.bookmarks.document-scope</key>
  <true/>
  <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
  <true/>
  <key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.audio-unit-host</key>
  <true/>
  <key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.mach-lookup.global-name</key>
  <array>
    <string>com.apple.midiserver</string>
    <string>com.apple.midiserver.io</string>
  </array>
</dict>
```