# AudioKit on MacOS X - How remove the security popup alert

Tags: macos, audiokit

I'm working on a Mac app using AudioKit as audio framework.
AudioKit works fine with MacOSX, the same as iOS, no issue with that!

I needed to turn the Sanbox settings to On as it is required for sending app to Mac AppStore, so I had to change the SandBox entitlements to get it works (related post: [Audiokit crashes when enabling sandbox in OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49115091/audiokit-crashes-when-enabling-sandbox-in-os-x)).
The app works fine, except that I have this dirty security message during app launch saying « Use of the requested Audio Unit(s) require lower the security settings. Are you sure you want to proceed ».

[image]

I suppose this alert is caused by the line « com.apple.security.temporary-exception.audio-unit-host » in the entitlements file.

As my app is not a Audio Unit Host, I should be able to remove this line, but it might also require some changes in AudioKit framework. This is doable as AudioKit is open-source.

My problem is where should I look in the AudioKit framework to remove the Audio Unit Host related code ? Is this doable ? I hope so...

Any help is welcomed!!